# Display only one plotshape

Tags: pine-script

I want to display only one plotshape in an hourly interval 8:15-10:00 based on the last high or low that is breaking the zone between 04:00-8:15.
See the code below:

```
bars_count(start, end)=>
    diff_unix_min = (end - start) / (1000 * 60)
    p = str.tonumber(timeframe.period)
    if timeframe.isdwm
        if timeframe.isdaily
            p := timeframe.multiplier * 60 * 24
        if timeframe.isweekly
            p := timeframe.multiplier * 60 * 24 * 7
        if timeframe.ismonthly
            p := timeframe.multiplier * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4
            
    math.floor(math.max(diff_unix_min / p, 1))


var bool highAboveSessionHigh = false
var bool lowBelowSessionLow = false
var bool loopBreak = false
var int firstArrowBar = 0


// Define the time range (8:15 to 10:00)
zStart = timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 8, 15)
zEnd = timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 10, 00)
tradeTime = time >= zStart  and time <= zEnd

candlesInSession = bars_count(zEnd,zStart)

// Loop through the specified number of session candles
for i = 0 to candlesInSession
    highAboveSessionHigh := high[i] > ONsessionHighPrice and tradeTime ? true : false
    lowBelowSessionLow := low[i] < ONsessionLowPrice and tradeTime ? true : false

    if (highAboveSessionHigh or lowBelowSessionLow)
        loopBreak := true
        firstArrowBar := i+1
        break
    if loopBreak
        break

plotshape(lowBelowSessionLow, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), title='SELL', text='SELL')
plotshape(highAboveSessionHigh, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), title='BUY', text='BUY')
```

[chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSK2J.png)

I want only the last 'SELL' shape as that's the last candle that broke the low of the grey area. Hope this make sense.